# How to get an integral type which represents integers from -512 to +511? How to get an integral type which represents integers from -256 to +256?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, types, int

I'm a beginner in C#.

I'm looking for an integral type to represent integers from -512 to +511
(512 = 2^9)

and also an integral type to represent integers from -256 to +255
(256 = 2^8)

I have found the integral type `sbyte` which represents integers from -128 to +127
(128 = 2^7)
but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`short` (an alias for `System.Int16`) will cover all these use cases.

It has a range from -32768 to +32767.

Answer (score 1):

Any integral type 2 bytes or larger will allow these numbers. `short` (16-bit) is the smallest of these.

In programming; we don't define data types based on range, but on how much memory they use. The sizes are always in whole bytes, and some power of 2. Then we pick a data type with a large enough range (presumably the smallest necessary to save memory, though memory is cheap now).

A list of integral types can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx).